# Como generar un log en java netbeans 18

Tags: java, log4j

estoy intentando generar un log para que se guarde en un directorio en concreto con extension .txt sin embargo cuando ejecuto el programa el mismo me indica lo siguiente:

**log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.invmiranda.SistemaLisa).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.**

El archivo del propertie es el que se muestra en la imagen
[image: es el archivo de mis propiedades]

El IDE es Netbeans18 Si la respuesta esta a su alcance se los agradeceria mucho

Comment: ¿Ya [buscaste en el sitio](/q/137898)?

Answer (score 0):

El error:

> log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger
> (com.invmiranda.SistemaLisa). log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j
> system properly

indica simplemente un **problema de inicialización de [log4j](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/)**, debes definir la ruta correcta del archivo de configuración usando la clase `DOMConfigurator` y definir el nombre de tu clase:

```
DOMConfigurator.configure("src/log4j.xml"); 
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MiClase.class);
```

Answer (score -1):

Yo creo que es más fácil utilizar tu propio código que utilizar una lib externa. Podrías hacer algo así:

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(<log_file>, true);
fw.write(generarLog());
fw.close();
        
generarLog:
        
Calendar calendario = Calendar.getInstance();
String fecha = calendario.get(5) + "/" + calendario.get(2) + "/" + calendario.get(1) + " " + calendario.get(10) + ":" + calendario.get(12) + ":" + calendario.get(13);
return '[' + fecha + "]: " + <log> + '\n';
```

Log: [día/mes/año hora:minuto:segundo]: mensaje

Comment: log4j es un estándar en la industria.

Comment: Bueno, pero que es mejor, arreglarlo o buscar otra solución?

Comment: Arreglarlo, sin lugar a dudas. log4j está optimizado, probado y tiene un mantenimiento excelente. Tu método no tiene ni la décima parte de configurabilidad, no permite generar diferentes archivos de texto en función del día/hora, no permite pasarle una excepción directamente, no estoy seguro de qué pasaría si lo usas concurrentemente... qué vas, a implementar todo eso? Los estándares son estándares por un motivo, son librerías en las que confían y colaboran cientos de personas y que son probadas **muy** a fondo.